# Does the 3D Ising model violate the hyperscaling relation?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, field-theory, renormalization, ising-model

The hyperscaling relation relates two critical exponents $\{\alpha,\nu\}$ (the power the divergence of the specific heat $c$ and correlation length $\zeta$ near a critical temperature $T_c$) as follows:
$$ \nu d = 2-\alpha, $$
which one can derive by doing RG near the Wilson-Fisher fixed point.

Therefore, in order for the specific heat to be strictly positive ($\alpha > 0$), either $\nu < 2/d$, or the hyperscaling relation has to be violated. However, the former case appears to be rigorously ruled out by an energy fluctuation argument, https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.57.2999, which means that a strictly positive $\alpha$ has to imply the violation of the hyper scaling relation.

However, there is pretty good numerical evidence that $\alpha > 0$ for the $3d$ Ising model, https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.6064. Does this mean that the $3d$ Ising model violates the hyperscaling relation then? This seems like a very strange conclusion because the upper critical dimension of the Ising model is $4$, so I think I must be misunderstanding something.

Comment: The former article is about disordered systems which imply random interactions or fields. The later article is about the Ising model with no random interactions or fields. Disordered systems have properties very different from that of systems with no disorder.

Comment: @Gec I think the arguments in the former article is fairly general. It applies to percolation, which I think can be extended to a pure Ising model via the FK representation (correlated percolation).

Comment: The currently estimated values of the critical exponents of the 3d Ising model (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_critical_exponents)) are perfectly compatible with the hyperscaling relation. My guess is that the paper by Chayes *et al* does not apply in this case. I read it several decades ago, but don't remember it well enough to comment on it.

Comment: @Yvan I'm not familiar with conformal bootstrapping, so please correct me if I'm wrong. But isn't assuming conformal invariance at the 3d Ising critical point will by definition make the hyper scaling relation true?

Comment: Honestly, I am not that familiar with it either, so I prefer to abstain. However their estimates are compatible with those obtained using alternative approaches (although conformal bootstrap does provide much more precise estimates), so I'd say that all this seems to confirm the validity of the hyperscaling relation (in 3d).

Comment: I haven't read the linked article, but one generally expects the specific heat exponent to be negative at a disordered fixed point, see e.g. Ma, *Modern Theory of Critical Phenomena*. So the result $\nu > 2/d$ would follow from that result and assuming hyperscaling holds. And yes, at a conformal field theory hyperscaling should hold.